# Тайцы, но Таиланд

Tags: орфография

Почему нужно писать "Таиланд" через И, если народность называется "тайцы", а не "таицы"?

Answer (score 1):

"Обожаю" вопросы, начинающиеся с "почему". Да потому, что язык так устроен.
Вас не смущает, что "идти", но "прийти"? Война, но воин? 
А то, что в Уэльсе живут валлийцы?

Comment: Как я уважаю Вас за такие ответы!!!

Comment: На любые вопросы даём любые ответы.

Comment: Я имел в виду не пространные перепечатки из словарей или учебников,как это часто бывает на нашем форуме, а живое, эмоциональное пояснение, основанное на собственном понимании языковых процессов.

Comment: А я считаю, что отвечать нужно тогда, когда знаешь ответ. А если не знаешь, совершенно не обязательно унижать человека, который спрашивает. Не так уж много народа сейчас вообще озадачиваются языковыми вопросами. Так давайте и у тех, что есть, отобьем охоту.  
Советую Вам просто не отвечать на вопрос, если не знаете ответа, или делать это как-то деликатнее. Кажется, мы с Вами уже говорили на эту тему.  
Почему та же olsa может отвечать так, что вопрошающий не чувствует себя полным дауном за то, что задал вопрос?

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki
>Почему та же olsa может отвечать так, что вопрошающий не чувствует себя полным дауном за то, что задал вопрос?  
Не могу знать, товарищ пропорщик. Разрешите спросить у неё?
Вы таких ответов от меня ждёте? Читая Ваши комментарии, полным дауном чувствую себя я. Вы не можете знать, как чувствует себя спрашивающий. И вы заведомо искажаете смысл моих ответов. И если вопрос задан так, что не предполагает правильного ответа, то ни olsa, ни кто другой, не ответит на него правильно. Деликатность никогда мерилом правильности не была.
Примите мои уверения в совершеннейшем к Вам почтении

Comment: ЗЫ Свой ответ на данный вопрос считаю правильным в том смысле, что дает полное представление о ситуации и сформулирован в понятных спрашивающиму терминах.
Истино же правильный ответ на вопрос с "почему" должен содержать изложение причинно-следственной связи между интересующими спрашивающего объектами. Когда такой связи нат и быит не может (а в лингвистике это почти всегда так), ничего не остаётся как объясняьть это на близких аналогиях. "Интересующийся" человек это должен понять.

Comment: Таиланд - традиционное написание. Сейчас иногда встречается и Тайланд, особенно в инетовских зарисовках с натуры.

Comment: Иногда встречается и *"звОнит"* и *"ложить"*.